# VirtueMart Custom Address Fields

Tags: php, joomla, e-commerce, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I'm building a shipping module for Virtuemart 2 for a South African Courier Company, and I need to add a few extra fields to the addresses, and change some existing ones.

I have to add Location Type (Drop down), Building Details (Text) and pre-populate state and city with my own fields (Drop down).

I already managed to find a solution for State, as there is a database table called _virtuemart_states, and adding to that seems to work. However, that’s about as far as I get...

The extra fields should be read and saved by my shipping module for later use... And should also be saved to the address so that a client can check out later using the same address.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

I think the VM2.x is already providing those option.
You can add as many as custom address fields from back end

```
Under configuration of VM - > Shopper Fields.

www.yousite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=userfields
```

If you are planning for shipping plugin just check the code for creating custom address fields and try that in your plugin .

Hope its help you..